How to create a box shadow effect when overlaying an image on a video using FFmpeg?
I'm working on a video project where I need to overlay an image on a background video. I've managed to achieve the basic overlay using the following FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i image_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4

This command overlays the image on the background video, centered. However, I would like to add an effect similar to a CSS box shadow, where the overlaid image has a shadow that gradually fades out, giving it a sense of depth.
I've tried various combinations of FFmpeg filters, such as boxblur, gblur, and drawbox, but I can't quite achieve the desired effect.
I'm attaching two images to illustrate what I have and what I'm trying to achieve:
The current result of my FFmpeg command : https://i.imgur.com/3uK79jP.png
An example of the desired box shadow effect : https://i.imgur.com/KaIq7VI.png

Hello, "I tried", but there are no listed attempts. So voting to close. Save everyone's time by listing the commands that "didn't work" for you and reasons why they didn't suit you.

Also a crosspost: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/37354/how-to-create-a-box-shadow-effect-when-overlaying-an-image-on-a-video-using-ffmp
